# Gets Cannot read property 'count' of undefined error and ngTasty isn't working

Tags: angularjs

I just setup tasty for the first time. Just trying to test it with some sample data. I set it up initially like this :

html :

```
<div ng-controller="vehicleIndexController as vehicleIndexCtrl">
    <div tasty-table bind-resource-callback="vehicleIndexCtrl.getResource" bind-init="init" bind-filters="filterBy">
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            <thead tasty-thead></thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
                    <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ row.star }}</td>
                    <td>{{ row['sf-location'] }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div tasty-pagination></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller :

```
angular.module('shimizuApp')
    .controller('vehicleIndexController', function($scope) {
        var vehicleIndexCtrl = this;

        vehicleIndexCtrl.getResource = function(params, paramsObj) {
            var urlApi = 'panel/vehicles/list.json?' + params;
            return $http.get(urlApi).then(function(response) {
                return {
                    'rows': response.data.rows,
                    'header': response.data.header,
                    'pagination': response.data.pagination,
                    'sortBy': response.data['sort-by'],
                    'sortOrder': response.data['sort-order']
                }
            });
        }

    });
```

But when running I get an error like this :

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $ngTastyProvider <- $ngTasty <- vehicleIndexController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$injector/unpr?p0=%24ngTastyProvider%20%3C-%20%24ngTasty%20%3C-%20vehicleIndexController
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular-81e589960334ab03c12f10bb84f21c9a.js?body=1:69:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular-81e589960334ab03c12f10bb84f21c9a.js?body=1:4265:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular-81e589960334ab03c12f10bb84f21c9a.js?body=1:4412:39)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular-81e589960334ab03c12f10bb84f21c9a.js?body=1:4270:45
    at getService (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular-81e589960334ab03c12f10bb84f21c9a.js?body=1:4412:39)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular-81e589960334ab03c12f10bb84f21c9a.js?body=1:4444:13)
    at $get.extend.instance (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular-81e589960334ab03c12f10bb84f21c9a.js?body=1:9002:34)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular-81e589960334ab03c12f10bb84f21c9a.js?body=1:8112:36)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular-81e589960334ab03c12f10bb84f21c9a.js?body=1:7544:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular-81e589960334ab03c12f10bb84f21c9a.js?body=1:7548:13) <div ng-view="" class="view-animate ng-scope" data-ng-animate="1">
```

What might be the issue?

The app declaration :

```
angular.module('shimizuApp', ['ngMaterial', 'templates', 'ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngTasty'])
```

Comment: where is your app declaration which shows your dependencies?

Comment: do you have `<script src="bower_components/ng-tasty/ng-tasty-tpls.min.js"></script>` in your HTML, and `angular.module('shimizuApp', ['ngTasty']);` declared?

Comment: @Claies Just added the app declaration. And yes I have tasty script added like this : `<script src="/assets/ng-tasty/ng-tasty-tpls.js?body=1"></script>`

Comment: err, what is that `?body=1` for?

Comment: @Claies Ah im using Angular inside Rails. That's a tag automatically added by rails. But the script is attached correctly.

Comment: which script is loaded first? the one for tasty or the one for your controller?

Comment: @Claies The one for tasty

Comment: hmm, looks like it's set up correctly; I noticed you posted in their bug forums, I would guess that they will have the resources to diagnose your error.

Comment: have you defined an init value for pagination? 
$scope.init = {};